# How to write in HTML DOM?

Tags: html, dom

In sample HTML DOM, how can I write code to add included statements for code? I tried:

```php
<?php $htmlh.='
    <?php include('../language/common.php'); ?>'
?>
```

But I’m getting errors. What did I miss?

How can I write correct code under HTML DOM?

Comment: you can't do this in .html files, you can do this in php file.

Comment: Check your quotes.  You need to escape single quotes inside of single quotes, or use double quotes.